# GetProfileInt() is failing

Tags: winapi, mapi

In my application, I am using the following Win32 API to before loading the mapi32.dll.
win32 API: `::GetProfileInt(_T("MAIL"), _T("MAPI"), 0);`

This API is consistently failing on Windows 8.1 Italian 64-Bit PC.

But, this API is succeeding on all other PCs like Windows 8.1 English(US) 64-Bit PC, Windows 8.1 Japanese 64-Bit PC.

Kindly provide your kind help for fixing the above issue.

Comment: How is this question related to MFC?

Answer (score 1):

To find MAPI32.dll look in either of these paths:

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mapi32.dll`

`C:\Windows\System32\mapi32.dll`

or use this

```
GetWindowsDirectory(buf, 260);
lstrcat(buf, TEXT("\\SysWOW64\\mapi32.dll"));
...
```

To access old win.ini settings, look in this registry key:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\win.ini`

But there is probably nothing there about MAPI, it's about 20 years out of date.

Answer (score 1):

The code you originally got this from was probably very old and is no longer supported. If you read [the documentation for `GetProfileInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you'll see that its purpose is to support 16-bit applications.

I recommend removing the call.  I have also observed it failing on Windows 7 machines while succeeding on Windows 10 machines. I think the more appropriate calls are to use `SearchPath(nullptr, L"MAPI32.DLL", nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr)` to see if MAPI32.DLL would even be found. An alternative is to just attempt the `LoadLibrary(L"MAPI32.DLL")` and check the returned handle.

An even better solution might be to change your code to call [`MAPISendMailHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as it will do the `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress`, etc. for you.